# Slim 3 - How to call methods without passing arguments

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

I am using slim bridge for DI.

Say, from AController i want to call the function 'second' in BController.

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Noodlehaus\Config as Config;

class BController extends Controllers {

public function second(Request $request, Response $response, Config $config, $optional = []){
    // do stuff
}
```

How could i call the second function passing only the parameter i want to send ($optional in this case) and not all other dependencies like request or response.

```
class AController extends Controllers{
    public function second(Request $request, Response $response, BController $bController){
        $bController->second(['custom parameter']);

        // or

        $this->container->get('App/Controllers/BCOntroller')->second();

        // i do not want this

        $bController->second($request, $response, $cache, etc etc);
    }
}
```

I tried to follow the route logic.'first' function gets executed without sending parameter

```
$app->get('/', ['\App\Controllers\AController', 'first']);
```

Comment: What functionality to you need from the second controller?

Comment: obviously second function ?

Comment: obviously.  good luck with that.

Comment: the question itself  is not remotely related to the functionality of the second function. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Your question indirectly implies that `App/Controllers/BController::second()` contains a piece of application logic (otherwise why would you want to invoke it without passing request/response pair?). If this is the case, then you're facing the problem of breaking single responsibility principle - each component should do one thing only. The task of any controller is to process request and return response. That is why @Rob asked you a question about what `App/Controllers/BController::second()` does.

Since you want the same logic executed when `AController::second()` method is invoked, the best solution for you would be to extract application logic from `App\Controllers\BController::second()` to a separate service and invoke it wherever you want.

Then inject the service from inside the controller when neccessary.

As for exact answer to your question - no, you cannot invoke that method, because method signature requires `$request` and `$response` arguments.